# In Spring RabbitMQ I throw AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException but message still requeue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

My service listens to RabbitMQ queue. I configure retry policy in consumer side. When I throw exception, all dead-letter messages requeue. But depend on my business logic, after throwing StopRequeueException (every exception except SmsException) I want to stop retry for this message. But the message still requeue.
Here is my configuration

```yaml
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    listener:
      simple:
        retry:
          enabled: true
          initial-interval: 3s
          max-attempts: 10
          max-interval: 12s
          multiplier: 2
        missing-queues-fatal: false
```

```java
if (!checkMobileService.isMobileNumberAdmitted(mobileNumber())) {
    throw new StopRequeueException("SMS_BIMTEK.MOBILE_NUMBER_IS_NOT_ADMITTED");
}
```

My error handler:

```java
public class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        if (!(t.getCause() instanceof SmsException)) {
            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Error Handler converted exception to fatal", t);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the error handler is outside the scope of retry; it is called after retries are exhausted.

You need to classify which exceptions are retryable at the retry level and do the conversion in the recoverer.

Here is an example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So67406799Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So67406799Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitRetryTemplateCustomizer customizer(
            @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts}") int attempts) {

        return (target, template) -> template.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(attempts,
                Map.of(StopRequeueException.class, false), true, true));
    }

    @Bean
    MessageRecoverer recoverer() {
        return (msg, cause) -> {
            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Stop requeue after " +
                    RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount() + " attempts");
        };
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so67406799")
    void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        if (in.equals("dontRetry")) {
            throw new StopRequeueException("test");
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("so67406799");
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class StopRequeueException extends NestedRuntimeException {

    public StopRequeueException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

The customizer is called once by Spring Boot; it is called after the retry policy and back off policy have been set up. See `RetryTemplateFactory`.

In this case, the customizer replaces the retry policy with a new one with an exception classifier (that's why we need the max attempts injected here).

See the `SimpleRetryPolicy` constructor.

```java
    /**
     * Create a {@link SimpleRetryPolicy} with the specified number of retry attempts. If
     * traverseCauses is true, the exception causes will be traversed until a match is
     * found. The default value indicates whether to retry or not for exceptions (or super
     * classes) are not found in the map.
     * @param maxAttempts the maximum number of attempts
     * @param retryableExceptions the map of exceptions that are retryable based on the
     * map value (true/false).
     * @param traverseCauses true to traverse the exception cause chain until a classified
     * exception is found or the root cause is reached.
     * @param defaultValue the default action.
     */
    public SimpleRetryPolicy(int maxAttempts, Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> retryableExceptions,
            boolean traverseCauses, boolean defaultValue) {
```

The last boolean in the config above (true) is the default behavior (retry exceptions that are not in the map), the third (true) tells the policy to follow the cause chain to look for the exception (like your `getCause()` in the error handler). The map `<Exception, Boolean>` says don't retry for this one.

You can also configure it the other way around (default `false` and `true` in the map values), explicitly stating which exceptions you want to retry and don't for all others.

The `MessageRecoverer` is called for all exceptions, either immediately for the classified exception or when retries are exhausted for the others.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I understand correctly, when project throws Exception then customizer is called, and for only StopRequeueException recoverer method will be called, for other exceptions after cusomizer method retry policy will be fulfilled. Am I right?

Comment: No; the customizer is called once by Spring Boot, during initialization. I added more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Your answer helped me a lot. Now it works as it should